# Moving arguments list from function to allocate class C++

Tags: c++, function, object, memory-management, arguments

I trying to move arguments list from function to class allocation.
Something like this:

```
SomeClass *func(...) {
    SomeClass Pointer   = new SomeClass(...);
    return Pointer;
}
```

Where ... there should be arguments list. Why it don't work, and can you tell me how this mechanism works (mid-lever :D)?

Comment: I have no clue as to what you are asking.

Comment: Guy who answered first at least tried ;P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your question, but I think you want to forward the arguments.

```
template <typename... Ts>
SomeClass *func(Ts&&... vs)
{
    SomeClass *p = new SomeClass(std::forward<Ts>(vs)...);
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is solution of my problem (thanks!). Sorry for my incomprehensible question. Can you explain me how it works on "mid-level"?

Comment: @rafalon There is a lot to explain here if that's all new to you, but many ressources can do that way better than me. The terms you have to look for are variadic templates (the ... stuff), rvalue references (&&), and std::forward.